# CXF does not allow me to return object in webmethod

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have a Message class and if i generate webmethod as a return Type Message it gives me

> The given SOAPAction http://main.tst.com/Gonder does not match an operation.

```
public class Message {

    private String Description;
    private String Status;
    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started to install eclipse-tomcat-cxf from beginning and problem was solved